# Embedded CSS with owasp-java-html-sanitizer

Tags: java, owasp

I am working on a project where we are allowing users to submit html/css and we will create a pdf out of that code. We have the code working, but I would like to sanitize the data that is coming in to prevent any attacks. There is a method to sanitize the inline css through:
http://javadox.com/com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer/owasp-java-html-sanitizer/r223/javadoc/org/owasp/html/HtmlPolicyBuilder.html#allowStyling(org.owasp.html.CssSchema)

But is there anything that can be used to check anything within a style tag? I do realize that embedded css may be too difficult to check, but I couldn't find anything in my google searches on this topic. The CssSchema seems to check every property I need, I just cannot apply it to what is between the style tags?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question was use AntiSamy. 
http://atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.owasp.antisamy/antisamy/1.5.3/org/owasp/validator/css/CssScanner.html
This class gave me everything I need. It allows me to scan external, embedded and inline css. I am currently working on the inline, because I think I have to pull out each inline element individually. I did have to strip out the Style tags in order to use CssScanner with scanStyleSheet, but it worked.